# How do I make 3 columns on a single line in a document?

Tags: spacing, columns

I'm writing up a report in Latex and on one of the lines I'd like to have 3 headings 'Case 1', 'Case 2' and 'Case 3'. How do I do this just for one of the lines in the document?

Comment: You want only to insert 3 pieces evenly spaced? What about the alignment? Maybe `\noindent{Case 1}\hfill{Case 2}\hfill{Case 3}`?

Comment: Yeah, just those 3 headings with one on the far left, one in the centre and one on the far right. Your answer nearly worked, it put Case 1 and Case 3 in the right places but Case 2 isn't in the centre? It's right next to Case 1

Comment: do you want the middle one to be centred on the page or centred between the left and right texts?

Comment: There is couple dozen answers to this questions, depending on what exactly do you need. So unless you provide more context, the answers very likely won't fit in your needs.

Comment: It seems likely that you really want to make a table, with these as headings. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_tabular_environment

Answer (score 5):

this should work for one line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\leavevmode\rlap{Long left text}\hfill
  Center text\hfill\llap{Right}\par

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

this is a "standard" method for handling 3-part running heads.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 suggestions:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
First line, indented because it begins a paragraph.
\par\noindent%
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
Case 1 & Case 2 & Case 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\par\noindent%
Last line.

First line, indented because it begins a paragraph.
\par\noindent%
Case 1 \hfill Case 2 \hfill Case 3
\par\noindent%
Last line.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to use `\hfill` instead.

Comment: note in both versions Case 2 is centred between Case 1 and Case 3 rather than being in the centre of the page. (Perhaps that's what the OP wants anyway) it is same thing here as case 1 and case 3 are same width, but try Case 11111111111 to see the difference